# AEM Adaptive Forms using ACS Commons component not storing data

Tags: forms, aem

I have an adaptive form (custom adaptive form template based on survey template) that has a submit action to store data in the JCR.
I'm using `column-control` component from `ACS Commons` to work as a layout for my form.
The problem i'm facing is that every component that i put inside the `column-control`, this value isn't being saved.
If i put a `textbox` inside the `column-control` component, the value is not saved but if i put a `textbox` outside the `column-control` then the value is saved.

What do i need to change? the `post.POST.jsp` that stores the data? or the `column-control` component?

Comment: I would assume that as long as your textbox is inside the form elements it should work fine.  Is your data making it to your post JSP?